# Create new pod when old pod dies or crossed threshold

Tags: linux, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, azure-aks

I am new bee to Kubernetes and I am doing some workaround on these pods.
I have 3 pods running in 3 different nodes. One of the Pod App is taking more usage 90+ and I want to create a health check for that.
Is there any way for creating a health check in Kubernetes ?
If I mention 80 CPU limit, Kubernetes will create new pod or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to scale pods. There is a simple [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) that will walk you through creating one. Here's a resource example from the mentioned guide:

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: php-apache
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the below answer , you are supposed to create a horizontal autoscaler component for that deployment object, the kubernetes metrics server will continuously be keeping watch on CPU utilization against each POD and once the usage crosses the threshold i.e. "averageUtilization: 50" ( as mentioned below ), then a new pod will get spawned once the existing pod reaches 50% of the CPU provided to it.

And this is different from health check thing, as health of a pod is decides whether to send traffic on that or not i.e. via liveness and readiness probes.

Make sure you mention the resources and limits for the POD in the deployment file that you create, so that HPA can take a reference value of CPU against which it will be calculating the percentage of utilization.